# Pointer Arithmetic With Same Pointer (Array Subscript is not an Integer)

Tags: c, gcc, clang, c99

I just want to make sure my interpretation of what is going on here is correct. Consider the following snippet of code that is compiled on a 32-bit environment and declared on the stack.

```
// Declares an array of integers with a length of 10.
int arr[ 10 ] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

// Performs some pointer arithmetic.
int result = arr[ arr + 2 ];
```

Now I know that using the square braces in C is just an alias for the following.

```
*( ... )
```

So, following that aliasing, the snippet would translate to the following.

```
int result = *( arr + arr + 2 );
```

Now, my interpretation is that the pointer arithmetic will evaluate to the address of arr plus 2 multiplied by the size of an integer, plus the address of arr. Hence, my conclusion is that arr will point to memory I have not allocated. This will cause result to be some garbage value.

However, when I compile with both clang and gcc I receive an error saying "array subscript is not an integer". Why is this the case and where did my interpretation go wrong?

Comment: You can't index an array with a pointer.

Comment: Your array of size 10 has 11 elements.

Comment: (How C "evaluates" an expression, and what it considers valid syntax are two different things.)

Comment: @JakeWilson, fixed -- I re-wrote my code for this post and naturally performed a human mistake.

Comment: @JacobPollack, some of the commentators on SO are not very tolerant.  Your code was close to being correct and understanding why it was not working is important.  Please re-review all of the answers to your question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The array subscript is not an integer.

Pointer arithmetic is limited to:

- pointer - pointer (yielding an integer)
- pointer + integer (yielding a pointer)
- pointer - integer (yielding a pointer).

You cannot add two pointer values, simply because there's no reasonable meaning for the result.

What did you expect `arr[ arr + 2 ]` to do? Update: I see you addressed that; you expected it to refer to some garbage address. This is a case where the language prevents you from generating garbage. Don't expect it to do that in all cases.

Comment: From your answer, is pointer +-/* pointer arithmetic then considered to be undefined in C (and respectively handled on a compiler level)?

Comment: @JacobPollack: Yes, the error is handled at compile time. It's a constraint violation, like adding a struct and a union or calling an integer. You can think of it as "illegal", but the language standard doesn't express it that way. (A conforming compiler must issue at least one diagnostic message for any translation unit that violates a constraint or syntax rule. That diagnostic *can* be a mere warning.)

Comment: Ok, thank you. Can you clarify one more question? That being, how come it's considered valid to perform subtraction of two pointers, but not addition? Would they not both yield the same meaningless result? If not can you provide a case to disprove me.

Comment: @JacobPollack: `pointer - pointer` gives you the number of elements between the two pointers if they point to different elements of the same array (and if they don't, the subtraction has undefined behavior), `pointer + pointer` doesn't yield a meaningful pointer.

Comment: That makes sense, a little critical thinking and I should have been able to figure that out (sorry). Thanks for discussing this with me, your time is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Except for one letter your code should work!! The value within the [] needs to be an integer, so dereference arr+2 :

```
// Declares an array of integers with a length of 10.
int arr[ 10 ] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

// Performs some pointer arithmetic.
int result = arr[ *(arr + 2) ];
```

this should produce result = arr[2]; thus result = 2

I ran this on Eclipse/Microsoft C compiler and got exactly that result.

Finally, the convention of `arr + 2` is discussed in K&R, there is ABSOLUTELY NOTHING wrong with what you were trying to do.

Just for fun try: `int result = *(arr + *(arr + 2));`